# How to update chart.js in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, chart.js

I have created a chart.js vue component which renders with some data which is passed to it through props. Now I want to be able to call the update() method on the chart when the data changes. My issue is that with the way my code is structured I cannot do the usual chart.update() method as I can't access the chart variable from outside the function it was created in. How could I restructure my code so that I can call the update method on the chart?

At the moment when the data changes I just call the initial render function which causes the charts to be layered onto each other. This can be seen when you change the data then hover over the chart.

```js
Vue.component('chart', {
    template: '<canvas id="chart"></canvas>',
    props: {
        savings: Object,
    },
    watch: { 
        savings: {
            deep: true,
            handler() {
                console.log('Update Chart');
                this.createChart();
            }
        }
    },
    methods: {
        createChart() {
            new Chart(document.getElementById("chart"), {
                type: 'bar',
                data: {
                    datasets: [{
                        label: 'Bar Dataset',
                        data: [
                         this.savings.annual[0], 
                            this.savings.annual[1], 
                            this.savings.annual[2], 
                            this.savings.annual[3],
                            this.savings.annual[4]
                        ]
                    }, {
                        label: 'Line Dataset',
                        data: [
                         this.savings.cumulative[0], 
                            this.savings.cumulative[1], 
                            this.savings.cumulative[2], 
                            this.savings.cumulative[3],
                            this.savings.cumulative[4]
                        ],
                        type: 'line'
                    }],
                    labels: ['Year One', 'Year Two', 'Year Three', 'Year Four', 'Year Five']
                }
            });
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.createChart();
        console.log(this.totals);
    }
});

var app1 = new Vue({
    el: '#savings_calculator',
    data: {
        savings: {
         annual: [123,345,234,234,523],
            cumulative: [234,523,234,423,100],
        }
    },
    methods: {
     changeData() {
         for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
             Vue.set(this.savings.annual, i, Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000) + 1));
                Vue.set(this.savings.cumulative, i, Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000) + 1));
            }
         
        }
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="savings_calculator">
    <div class="input container">
        <button v-on:click="changeData">Change Data</button>
        <chart 
            v-bind:savings="savings"
        />
    </div>
</div>
```

I am working in WordPress and I have included the chart.js library by copying the code into one of my js files which all get minified and compressed into one file by gulp. I only mention this because I've seen examples where people use import to include the library. I did download the library into my node_modules but I couldn't get the import to work in my js files. It gave me the following error:

```
“Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module”
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue mainly happening because you are drawing multiple charts on the same `canvas` on calling the `createChart()` method. You just need to call the [`.destroy()`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/api.html#destroy) method to destroy any chart instances that were created. This will clean up any references stored to the chart object within Chart.js, along with any associated event listeners attached by Chart.js. This must be called before the canvas is reused for a new chart.

So, simply add a new data option to store current chart instance like:

```
data(){
  return{
    chart: null
  }
},
```

then store the chart instance like:

```
 createChart() {
    this.chart = new Chart(document.getElementById("chart"), {
    ...
```

and inside `watch` before calling `this.createChart();` use:

```
  this.chart.destroy();
  this.createChart();
```

**Working Demo:**

```js
Vue.component('chart', {
  template: '<canvas id="chart"></canvas>',
  props: {
    savings: Object,
  },
  data(){
    return{
      chart: null
    }
  },
  watch: {
    savings: {
      deep: true,
      handler() {
        console.clear();
        console.log('Update Chart');
        this.chart.destroy();
        this.createChart();
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    createChart() {
      this.chart = new Chart(document.getElementById("chart"), {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
          datasets: [{
            label: 'Bar Dataset',
            data: [...this.savings.annual]
          }, {
            label: 'Line Dataset',
            data: [...this.savings.cumulative],
            type: 'line'
          }],
          labels: ['Year One', 'Year Two', 'Year Three', 'Year Four', 'Year Five']
        }
      });
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.createChart();
    //console.log(this.totals);
  }
});

var app1 = new Vue({
  el: '#savings_calculator',
  data: {
    savings: {
      annual: [123, 345, 234, 234, 523],
      cumulative: [234, 523, 234, 423, 100],
    }
  },
  methods: {
    changeData() {
      for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        Vue.set(this.savings.annual, i, Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000) + 1));
        Vue.set(this.savings.cumulative, i, Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000) + 1));
      }

    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="savings_calculator">
  <div class="input container">
    <button v-on:click="changeData">Change Data</button>
    <chart v-bind:savings="savings" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks. I did have to change the following syntax for my project. ```data() { return{chart: null } }``` to ```data: { chart: null }```